# Play Integrity test cases failed

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

Below are the test cases that we created on Play Console for Play Integrity:

We have created combinations of different verdicts that can be received by Play Integrity API. All below test cases work when we remove all google accounts from a device and keep only that email ID with which the test case is created. But these test cases don't seem to work when a device has multiple google accounts.

Test case 1 - device 1:

As per the test case, the verdict returned should be "Basic device integrity met, running unlicensed Play-recognised app" but received below verdict:

```
               `"appIntegrity": {
        "appRecognitionVerdict": "UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION",
        "certificateSha256Digest": ["KrKTIuq1ehCAmzZmpBnECGnylNUIhJNKmG3cIYU-xU8"],
        "packageName": "mypackagename",
        "versionCode": "228"
    },
    "deviceIntegrity": {
        "deviceRecognitionVerdict": ["MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"]
    },
    "accountDetails": {
        "appLicensingVerdict": "LICENSED"
    }`
```

With this verdict, the message displayed on mobile app is - "App is not google play recognized"

When we removed all accounts and kept only device 1 test case email account in the same device, we got the expected result.:

```
    `"appIntegrity": {
        "appRecognitionVerdict": "PLAY_RECOGNIZED",
        "certificateSha256Digest": ["ki_C3iCaCK58mqf7FNrVH6KsPa8wDxBPsx_NQ37Qslw"],
        "packageName": "mypackagename",
        "versionCode": "228"
    },
    "deviceIntegrity": {
        "deviceRecognitionVerdict": ["MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY"]
    },
    "accountDetails": {
        "appLicensingVerdict": "UNLICENSED"
    }`
```

With this verdict, the message displayed on mobile app is - "Integrity check fail"

Test case 2 - device 2:

The only exception is this device where all test cases work in spite of the device having multiple google accounts.

As per the test case, the verdict returned should be "Strong device integrity met, running licensed Play-recognised app" which is correctly returned:

```
    `"appIntegrity": {
        "appRecognitionVerdict": "PLAY_RECOGNIZED",
        "certificateSha256Digest": ["ki_C3iCaCK58mqf7FNrVH6KsPa8wDxBPsx_NQ37Qslw"],
        "packageName": "mypackagename",
        "versionCode": "228"
    },
    "deviceIntegrity": {
        "deviceRecognitionVerdict": ["MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY"]
    },
    "accountDetails": {
        "appLicensingVerdict": "LICENSED"
    }`
```

With above verdict, no error message is displayed on mobile app and user successfully proceeds to next screen.

Tested same cases on few devices it's not working properly.

Comment: Are you sure that you've implemented it right ? Can you show the Android code part ?